# Prevent accidental check-in of password file using git

Tags: git

git does not seem to do what I want here so I need some advise. I have a configuration file with sensitive information such as passwords. Say I have checked in the config file with blank/generic values:

```
username =
password =
```

Now I fill it with real values, and then add the file to .gitignore (the filename is build.properties)

```
username = bob
password = secretpassword
```

Even though I have added it to .gitignore, git still seems to "see it". What should I do here?

```
hostname$ more .gitignore 
build
ant.build
*.swp
build.properties

hostname$ git status
# On branch dev
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   build.properties
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: So just to clarify, it seems if someone does `git -a -m 'whatever'` it will automatically check in the passwords still yes?

Comment: yes, if it is under version control it will be included in the commit

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`.gitignore` will only ignore files not already checked in. In your case you need to create an password.file.template and check that in, then put your password.file in the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 4):

Well it says *modified:   build.properties*, so someone has checked-in this file already. Best guess of mine would be: delete the file, commit the changes and then re-create it without checking-in.

Comment: Yes as I stated in the question, I have checked in a generic version of the config file as a template, so it is clear what the user must enter in the build file.

Comment: OK, when you want to distribute the template then you can't add this to the .gitignore file anyway (since git won't pick it up that way). So why not create a build.properties.template file and check that in? You can then instruct other developers to remove the .template part of that file and fill-in their credentials

Comment: This is how I do it with SVN too. Create a template file as ie. config.sample.txt, then place the actual config file as an ignored file so that it can't be commited accidentally.